# Form inside a bootstrap 2.x popover

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I inline the form inside a pop over in bootstrap?

**Link:**

```
<a href="#" id="popover"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Tab</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#popover').popover({ 
    html : true,
    title: function() {
      return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
      return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">Add new tab</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
    <!-- my form -->
      <input type="text" />
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >
        <i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn" type="button" />
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

As the comment below say, I think its about the `popover` size. I tried to modify it but it seems I'm lacking something:

```
.popover {
    max-width: 150px;
    width: auto;
}
```

I also added the codes related to the popover for more clearer view to you guys.

Comment: what is the width of your popup? is it fixed? i think, your form is already inline, but the width of popup is pushing it down

Comment: I didn't set the popup size, so i guess its the default size

Comment: check for it, may be it is fixed

Comment: I saw some post its using max-width I tried to override it. Not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'input-append' functionallity of bootstrap 2.x.
No need to use 'form-inline' that way, just 'form' will do:

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-append">
         <input id="appendedInputButtons" type="text">
         <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
         <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

More info here:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

**EDIT:**

full example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .popover {
            max-width: 150px;
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">

        </div>

        <a href="#" id="popover"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Tab</a>

        <div id="popover-head" class="hide">Add new tab</div>
          <div id="popover-content" class="hide">

            <form>
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-append">
                   <input class="span6" id="appendedInputButtons" type="text">
                   <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
                   <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </form>

          </div>

        <div class="span3">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
       $('#popover').popover({ 
        html : true,
        title: function() {
          return $("#popover-head").html();
        },
        content: function() {
          return $("#popover-content").html();
        }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work I think doniyor is right. Its about the size of popover

Comment: Strange.. Well, ok. Did you set the width of the input in pixels? Hardcoded? Maybe if you use percentage, like '.input-append{ width:100% } it could work. Anyway, the form-inline is a bit buggy I noticed, so i  don't actually like to use it anyway.

Comment: It really appends the buttons in the text but the size of the textbox + 2 buttons exceeds the length of the popover. I want to resize the popover but cant work it out. I updated my post above for much clearer view for you.

Comment: I updated the response. The full example code works for me. He doesn't put the buttons on the next line, he just shortens the input field.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstand me. The looks that I want to achieve is [this](http://dailyjs.com/images/posts/x-editable.png)

Comment: In that case, add the following to .popover in css: 'white-space: nowrap;' and adjust the length of the input field. For example by giving it a class like 'span4'. If you use LESS, you can make the width of the popover linked (with parameters) with the width of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

use this [link](http://bootply.com/89823) its hepfull for you

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
 html: true, 
content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
});
```

Comment: I already see that post. Its using bootstrap 3. That is why I ask again.